# Hibernate Lazy Load is Recursively Loading Set or Referencing data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, recursion, lazy-loading

I am having some strange issues with Hibenate lazy loading. I have 2 entities ProcessEntity and SectionEntity. A ProcessEntity can have many SectionEntity's and the SectionEntity should know which ProcessEntity it belongs to (@OneToMany). The problem I am having is when I load a ProcessEntity with `hibernateTemplate.get(id)` and then call my custom function `fetchLazyCollections(entity, ...)` which loops the entities methods until it finds a PersistentCollection and then forces a lazy load on that method.

When the ProcessEntity has its Set lazy loaded it recursively loads ALL the data in the SectionEntity meaning it loads the ProcessEntity which loads the SectionEntitys which load the ProcessEntity and so on! This causes a stack overflow when I try to serialize the data and must be terrible for performance. This doesn't happen when I make an HQL query etc.

Here is my setup for the Entities:

ProcessEntity:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "processes")
public class ProcessEntity extends Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id = Entity.UNSAVED_ID;

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="process")
    private Set<SectionEntity> sections = new HashSet<SectionEntity>();

    ...

    public Set<SectionEntity> getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
    public void setSections(Set<SectionEntity> sections) {
        this.sections = sections;
    }

    ...
}
```

SectionEntity:

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "sections")
public class SectionEntity extends Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id = Entity.UNSAVED_ID;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = ProcessEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="process", referencedColumnName="id")
    private ProcessEntity process;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ...

    public ProcessEntity getProcess() {
        return process;
    }
    public void setProcess(ProcessEntity process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    ...
}
```

fetchLazyCollections:

```java
public <E extends Entity> E fetchLazyCollections(E entity, String... specifiedCollections) {
    if(getCurrentSession() == null) {
        throw new SessionException("No session found for fetching collections.");
    }

    // Fetch the collections using reflection
    Class<? extends Entity> clazz = entity.getClass();
    for(Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
        Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
        if(ReflectUtils.isClassCollection(returnType)) {

            // Check if the collection type is specified via the getter
            List<String> specified = Arrays.asList(specifiedCollections);
            if(!specified.isEmpty()) {
                if(!specified.contains(method.getName())) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            try {
                // Check that the collection is persistent
                Collection collection = (Collection) method.invoke(entity);
                if(collection instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                    collection.size(); // invokes lazy loading
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return entity;
}
```

I am using Spring on my back-end making use of `@Transactional`. Here is my Hibernate spring module (@Configuration):

```java
@Configuration
@Import({
    MappingModule.class
})
@ImportResource("classpath:nz/co/doltech/ims/properties.xml")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateModule {

    private static int statisticId = 0;

    private @Value("#{app['root.path']}") String projectPath;
    private @Value("#{app['database.jndiname']}") String databaseJndiName;

    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.dialect']}") String hibernateDialect;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.hbm2ddl']}") String hibernateHbm2dll;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.show_sql']}") String hibernateShowSql;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.format_sql']}") String hibernateFormatSql;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.generate_statistics']}") String hibarnateStatistics;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.cache.provider_class']}") String hibarnateCacheProviderClass;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.cache.use_query_cache']}") String hibarnateQueryCache;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache']}") String hibarnateSecondLevelCache;
    private @Value("#{app['hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries']}") String hibernateStructuredEntries;

    private @Value("#{app['net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName']}") String hibernateEhcacheResource;

    private @Value("#{app['flyway.enabled']}") String flywayEnabled;
    private @Value("#{app['flyway.basePath']}") String flywayBasePath;

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean getDriverManagerDataSource() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();

        dataSource.setJndiName(databaseJndiName);
        dataSource.setCache(true);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    @DependsOn({"dataSource", "flyway"})
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean getAnnotationSessionFactoryBean() {
        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource((DataSource) getDriverManagerDataSource().getObject());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
            projectPath + ".server.entities",
            projectPath + ".server.entities.joins"
        });

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2dll);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", hibernateFormatSql);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", hibarnateStatistics);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", hibarnateCacheProviderClass);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", hibarnateQueryCache);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path", hibernateEhcacheResource);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.use_second_level_cache", hibarnateSecondLevelCache);
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", hibernateStructuredEntries);
        props.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");

        // caching resource
        //props.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", hibernateEhcacheResource);
        //props.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class", "nz.co.doltech.ims.server.persistence.TransactionManagerLookup");
        //props.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory");

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(props);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getHibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getAnnotationSessionFactoryBean().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name="hibernateTemplate")
    @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate();

        hibernateTemplate.setSessionFactory(getAnnotationSessionFactoryBean().getObject());

        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name="jmxExporter")
    @DependsOn("hibernateStatisticsBean")
    public MBeanExporter getJmxExporter() {
        MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        Properties props = AppProperties.getProperties();
        String name = props.getProperty(AppProperties.CLIENT_MODULE_NAME);
        String type = props.getProperty(AppProperties.CLIENT_RELEASE_STAGE);
        map.put("Hibernate:"+name+"[" + ++statisticId + "]-"+type+"=Statistics", 
            getHibernateStatisticsBean());

        exporter.setBeans(map);
        return exporter;
    }

    @Bean(name="hibernateStatisticsBean")
    public StatisticsService getHibernateStatisticsBean() {
        StatisticsService statsBean = new StatisticsService();

        statsBean.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        statsBean.setSessionFactory(getAnnotationSessionFactoryBean().getObject());

        return statsBean;
    }

    @Bean(name="incidentDao")
    @DependsOn("hibernateDao")
    public IncidentHibernateDao getIncidentDao() {
        IncidentHibernateDao incidentDao = new IncidentHibernateDao();

        //incidentDao.registerBroadcasterId(AtmosphereConst.UPDATE_ID_KEY);

        return incidentDao;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionTemplate")
    @DependsOn({"transactionManager"})
    @Scope("prototype")
    public TransactionTemplate getTransactionTemplate() {
        return new TransactionTemplate(getHibernateTransactionManager());
    }
}
```

This is the Hibernate output:

```
hibernateDao.get(...) called:
Hibernate: select processent0_.id as id27_0_, processent0_.description as descript2_27_0_, processent0_.name as name27_0_, processent0_.nametoken as nametoken27_0_, processent0_.order_value as order5_27_0_, processent0_.removed as removed27_0_ from processes processent0_ where processent0_.id=?

hibernateDao.fetchLazyCollections(...) called:
Hibernate: select incidentjo0_.process_id as process3_27_1_, incidentjo0_.incident_id as incident2_1_, incidentjo0_.process_id as process3_1_, incidentjo0_.incident_id as incident2_21_0_, incidentjo0_.process_id as process3_21_0_, incidentjo0_.completed as completed21_0_ from incident_process incidentjo0_ where incidentjo0_.process_id=?
Hibernate: select sections0_.process as process27_1_, sections0_.id as id1_, sections0_.id as id29_0_, sections0_.description as descript2_29_0_, sections0_.name as name29_0_, sections0_.order_value as order4_29_0_, sections0_.process as process29_0_, sections0_.removed as removed29_0_ from sections sections0_ where sections0_.process=?
```

Nothing else is called from that point.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I am out of ideas.

Appreciate any help I can get!

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: What kind of serialization, something like json? Also, loading recursively means, can you see it is actually firing queries recursively. When you have bi-directional mapping and try to debug and inspect an object you see the references recursively, but it is not actually a recursive, those are just object references.

Comment: The serialization doesn't affect this, the object is mapped to a DTO so hibernate proxy won't be invoked. The mapper accommodates for hibernate proxy objects/sets. When I debugged I checked the hibernate calls, added it to the main post.